# PDFMerger for Laravel - Cannot Run Script After Merge('browser')

Tags: php, pdf, merge

```
    $pdf = new \LynX39\LaraPdfMerger\PdfManage;

    $pdf->addPDF(storage_path('public/pdfTemp').'/myFile01.pdf', 'all');
    $pdf->addPDF(storage_path('public/pdfTemp').'/myFile02.pdf', 'all');

    $pdf->merge('browser', 'complete.pdf', 'L');

    // The code below is not running !! why??
    Storage::delete('pdfTemp/myFile01.pdf');
    Storage::delete('pdfTemp/myFile02.pdf');
```

Based on the code above,
I use PdfMerger for PHP Laravel Framework...

The problem is the code, which is after

> $pdf->merge('browser', 'complete.pdf', 'L');

and any code below the line will not running.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved my problem..

Just follow the code below

```
$pdf = new \LynX39\LaraPdfMerger\PdfManage;

$pdf->addPDF(storage_path('public/pdfTemp').'/myFile01.pdf', 'all');
$pdf->addPDF(storage_path('public/pdfTemp').'/myFile02.pdf', 'all');

// Merge and return to STRING first, and store in $result variable
$result = $pdf->merge('string', 'complete.pdf', 'L');

// Deleting files
Storage::delete('pdfTemp/myFile01.pdf');
Storage::delete('pdfTemp/myFile02.pdf');

//And finnaly get the string and Display to BROWSER as PDF
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
echo $result;
```

Hope it will help others.